# How to use double keyboard macro, or keyboard macro of keyboard macro?

Tags: keyboard-macros

First of all, I made a new keyboard macro called 'mac'.

> [F3] abcd [F4]
>
> M-x name-last-kbd-macro mac

Then, I can get 'abcd' by typing [F4] or M-x mac. I tried to get 'abcd' five times. So I made a new keyboard macro of keyboard macro.

> [F3] C-u 5 M-x mac [F4]

I expected to see 'abcdabcdabcdabcdabcd' when I typed [F4]. However, keyboard macro of keyboard macro made 'abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd' which is 10 times of 'abcd', rather than 5. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I suspect you managed to type `F4` twice by mistake at the end, causing it to run a second time.

Comment: @phils I can reproduce the problem on Emacs 25.1.9.1, so I don't think it's a accidental keypress

Comment: Ah, I see. I can't replicate in 24.5 or 25.1.1. `M-x report-emacs-bug`, methinks.

Comment: I found why my keyboard macro works twice. The problem was typing 'RET(enter)' when I define second keyboard macro. I exactly typed '[F3] C-u 5 M-x mac RET [F4]'. Sorry for my mistake. Typing 'RET' add abcd 5 times. So total 10 times of abcd are included in kbd macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug. Using `insert-kbd-macro` You can look at what's actually stored in the macros:

```
(fset 'm
   "a")

(fset 'n
   [?\M-x ?m return ?a])
```

I created a macro called `m` that just prints 'a', then created a second macro called `n` that calls `m`. It seems the second macro records the call to `m`, then records the output of `m` as though it's keyboard input.

The only solution I can find is to create the second macro, then use `edit-kbd-macro` to remove the doubled text. Not very convenient, really.

---

## Update:

I believe this has now been [fixed in the master branch](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25860), so should work from Emacs 26 on.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. I've been trying to figure out what's wrong for the last hour…